How to mutate_at to perform calculation on dataframe in R
I have two dataframes  df_cash_size and  df_funds
df_cash_size <- data.frame(Date = c("201401","201402","201403"), 
ID =c("F11","F22","F33"), Cash_size = c(11246,51301,30327))

df_funds  <- data.frame(Date = c("201401","201402","201403"), 
ID =c("F11","F22","F33"), Cash = c(881, 126, 277), Ohers = c(532,12,78), loan = c(98,45,12))

Function below get_data takes the above dataframes as an input to perform the calculations.
I am trying to use mutate_at  to get the two calculations:
Calculation:1  Cash =  (df_funds$Cash/100)*Cash_size
Calculation:2  Others = df_funds(Others + loan)/100*Cash_size
get_data <- function (df_funds ,df_cashsize){
  df_finals <- df_funds |>
    left_join(df_cashsize, by = c("ID", "Date")) |> 
    
    mutate_at(vars(-ID, -Date, -Cash_size), ~ (df_funds$Cash/100)*Cash_size)%>%
    
    pivot_longer(cols = c(3:5) , names_to = "Cash", values_to = "Values") |>
    mutate(Date = lubridate::ym(Date))
    
  return (df_finals)
}

cal_cash_df <- get_data (df_funds,df_cash_size)
cal_cash_df

Current Output
  Date       ID    Cash_size Cash  Values
  <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 2014-01-01 F11       11246 Cash  99077.
2 2014-01-01 F11       11246 Ohers 99077.
3 2014-01-01 F11       11246 loan  99077.
4 2014-02-01 F22       51301 Cash  64639.
5 2014-02-01 F22       51301 Ohers 64639.
6 2014-02-01 F22       51301 loan  64639.
7 2014-03-01 F33       30327 Cash  84006.
8 2014-03-01 F33       30327 Ohers 84006.
9 2014-03-01 F33       30327 loan  84006.

Expected Output
  Date       ID         Cash            Others
 
1 2014-01-01 F11       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
2 2014-01-01 F11       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
3 2014-01-01 F11       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
4 2014-02-01 F22       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
5 2014-02-01 F22       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
6 2014-02-01 F22       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
7 2014-03-01 F33       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
8 2014-03-01 F33       Calculation:1     Calculation:2
9 2014-03-01 F33       Calculation:1     Calculation:2

Calculation:1 column should only have Cash vals.
Calculation:1  Cash =  (df_funds$Cash/100)*Cash_size
Calculation:2 Should sum others + loan values and then divide by 100 and multiply to Cash_size
Calculation:2  Others = df_funds(Others + loan)/100*Cash_size

Do you want df_funds |>     left_join(df_cash_size, by = c("ID", "Date")) |>      mutate(Cash = Cash/100*Cash_size,            Others = (Ohers + loan)/100 * Cash_size) ?

Don't use mutate_at, it is superseded by pick(.) and across(.).

Please provide expected output in a literal form, not descriptive, please.

@r2evans i have added the expected outcome. hopefully this is somewhat helpful.

Nope, I am asking for literal output, numbers and all. Perhaps I'll figure it out. BTW, please try your own data. You have a typo Ohers and you use lower-case in your code, the reprex is inconsistent. More typos: df_cashsize versus df_cash_size, even within the function.

Also, (almost) "never" use df_funds$ inside a dplyr pipe that starts on df_funds. At best it is completely unnecessary or it errors quickly, at worst the state of the data where you use it is in a different order than the original df_funds and your data is silently corrupted.

Why do you want to pivot values to "Values" and then discard them in your expected output?

@r2evans i was trying to see the output of the mutate_at using pivot_longer to see what the output i get, as the expected outcome is different from the current output so i guess piovt_longer does not really apply to this function.

@r2evans df_cashsize and  df_cash_size  is not a typo.  df_cash_size  refers to dataframe  and  df_cashsize is what the function takes as an input.

You're missing it: your function is defined with the argument df_cashsize but internally it uses df_cash_size.
